# Node.js + CoffeeScript - modules/class confusion

Tags: javascript, node.js, coffeescript

I understand how to use Protoype in standard Javascript with Node.js and modules, but am having a rough time equating them in CoffeeScript.

Let's say I have a file called `mymodule.coffee`:

```
Module = {}

class MyModule

  constructor: (parameter) ->

    Module = this
    Module.parameter = parameter

  standardFunction = (parameter) ->

    return parameter

  callbackFunction = (parameter, callback) ->

    callback parameter

exports.MyModule = MyModule
```

And I have another file called `test.coffee` in the same directory, which I run via `coffee test.coffee`, but get an error `TypeError: Object #<MyModule> has no method 'standardFunction'` when trying to access the class `MyModule`:

```
myModule = require 'mymodule'
myModule = new myModule.MyModule 'parameter'

console.log myModule.standardFunction 'parameter'

myModule.callbackFunction 'parameter', (response) ->

  console.log 'Response: ' + response
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have mistake in a syntax:

```
standardFunction = (parameter) ->
    return parameter
```

should be

```
standardFunction : (parameter) ->
    return parameter
```

(`:` instead of `=`) The first one is converted to

```
standardFunction = function(parameter) {
    return parameter;
}
```

which gives you nothing (no relation to class), while the second one to

```
MyModule.prototype.standardFunction = function(parameter) {
    return parameter;
}
```

which is what you want.

By the way, you can use CoffeeScript in your constructor like this:

```
constructor: (parameter) ->
    @parameter = parameter
```

Comment: Right. And also as long as I know you can even skip @parameter = parameter in your constructor, because every parameters passed there will be automatically assigned to @ (this) ... see the online parser at http://coffeescript.org/

Comment: You can add a property right in the constructor with CoffeeScript: `constructor: (@parameter) ->`

Answer (score 0):

Just to be a bit more concise:

constructor:(@param)->

The above code will translate to this.param = param